# Why \d\+ or \d+ is not equal to \d* here?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Bash +debian.

To match port number at the end of info.

```
s="2017-04-17 08:16:14 INFO     connecting lh3.googleusercontent.com:443 from 111.111.111.111:26215"
echo $s  | sed  's/\(.*\):\(\d*\)/\2/'
26215
```

Let's match it with \d+ or \d+ in sed.

```
echo $s  | sed  's/\(.*\):\(\d\+\)/\2/'
echo $s  | sed  's/\(.*\):\(\d+\)/\2/'
```

All of them get the whole string as output.

```
2017-04-17 08:16:14 INFO connecting lh3.googleusercontent.com:443 from 111.111.111.111:26215
```

None of them can match port number at the end,why?

Comment: sed doesn't have `\d` character class... the first one works because `\d` is same as `d` and `d*` can be empty... `\2` is empty... `sed  's/\(.*\):\(\d*\)/\2/'` is simply deleting upto last `:` in the line.. you can replace `d` with any letter... `sed  's/\(.*\):\(\q*\)/\2/'`

Comment: As Sundeep said - `\d` does not work in `sed`. Use `[[:digit:]]` instead.

Comment: I had [similar issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/279368/sed-regular-expression-behaving-differently-than-in-vim-and-perl) when starting with `sed`... over time one tends to learn the lesson that there are way too many regex flavors out there...

Comment: The `+` ain't going to work very well either without [extended regexp](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Extended-regexps.html) enabled in sed.  `sed -E`.  The match groups can also be unescaped.

Comment: Do not edit answers into questions. You can use the "Add An Answer" button yourself to add an answer to your own question if you're inclined to do so.

Comment: Just for the record, your initial command `sed  's/\(.*\):\(\d*\)/\2/' ` seems to (falsely) worked but in reality will catch (due to *) the part between  `:` and `*`. If you make the port number a string like ffffff , your initial sed will return that string ffffff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an easier `sed` pattern to use:

```
$ echo "$s"  | sed  -nE 's/.*:([^:])/\1/p'
26215
```

As stated in comments, regular `sed` does not have `perl` meta characters. You need to use the POSIX character class of `[[:digit:]]`

Explanation:

```
sed  -nE 's/.*:([^:])/\1/p'
      ^                         only print if there is a match
       ^                        use ERE and you don't need to escape the parens
           ^                    capture up to the rightmost :
               ^    ^           -E means you don't need to escape parens
                  ^             all characters except :
                         ^      print if there is a match
```

Or, if you want to be more specific you want only digits:

```
$ echo "$s"  | sed  -nE 's/.*:([[:digit:]]+$)/\1/p'
26215
```

Note `+` to make sure there is at least one digit and `$` to match only at the end of the line.

There is a summary of different regex flavors [HERE](http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/tech/regexp.html). With `-E` sed is using ERE the same as egrep.

Comment: Nah, firing up sed when `echo ${s##*:}` does the trick? Surely you jest.

Answer (score 2):

`\d` is a PCRE extension not present in BRE or ERE syntax (as used by standard UNIX tools).

In this particular case, there's no need to use any tools not built into bash for this purpose at all:

```
s="2017-04-17 08:16:14 INFO     connecting lh3.googleusercontent.com:443 from 111.111.111.111:26215"
echo "Port is ${s##*:}"
```

This is a [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe); when dealing with small amounts of data, such built-in capabilities are much more efficient than running external tools.

There's also native ERE support built into the shell, as follows:

```
re=':([[:digit:]]+)$'
[[ $s =~ $re ]] && echo "Port is ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

[BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) also goes into detail on bash string manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is this:

```
 echo ${s##*:}
```

Learn your shell string operators.

Answer (score 0):

```
s="2017-04-17 08:16:14 INFO     connecting lh3.googleusercontent.com:443 from 111.111.111.111:26215"
```

1.grep

```
echo $s  |grep -Po  '\d+$'
```

2.ack

```
echo $s  |ack -o  '\d+$'
```

3.sed

```
echo $s  |sed  's/.*\://'
```

4.awk

```
echo $s  |awk -F:  '{print $NF}'
```

Comment: `echo $s` is somewhat buggy -- for instance, if your `s` contained a `*` surrounded by whitespace, it would be replaced with a list of files in the current directory. Use `echo "$s"` instead.

Comment: (Also, `grep -P` is a nonstandard extension -- it's not available on MacOS without GNU grep installed with MacPorts or Homebrew, for example; and may not even be available on barebone Linux systems that compiled GNU grep without its optional support for libpcre).

Answer (score 0):

*Self-answer by OP moved from question to community wiki answer, per [consensus on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que):*

---

There is no expression **\d** to stand for numbers in sed.

To get with awk simply with :

```
echo $s |awk -F: '{print $NF}'
26215
```